I'm training a model for Tamil speech-to-text conversion using Kaldi. I'm having issue with generating MFCC features using the `make_mfcc.sh` script
steps/make_mfcc.sh --nj 20 --cmd "run.pl" data/train exp/make_mfcc/train $mfccdir
steps/make_mfcc.sh --nj 20 --cmd run.pl data/train exp/make_mfcc/train
utils/validate_data_dir.sh: Successfully validated data-directory data/train
steps/make_mfcc.sh: [info]: no segments file exists: assuming wav.scp indexed by utterance.
run.pl: 20 / 20 failed, log is in exp/make_mfcc/train/make_mfcc_train.*.log

How do I solve this error?
Verified that wav.scp and text files are correctly formatted and sorted.
